# Input box how to stop input?

Tags: html

I have a HTML page.

I want to have a input box, that has a default value, that people can select, but not write over.  It if for a share link to the page.

How can I do this?

EDIT: Using readonly="readonly" works and satisfies the solution, but the mouse pointer becomes a stop sign.  I have chosen to use pure text instead of putting the share link into an input box.  A javascript/Jquery solution will be possible but I don't use scripts on my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give input box readonly property like

```
 <input type="text" id="a" value="abc" readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use it as

```
 <input type="text" id="a" value="abc" disabled="true"/>
```

you can also dynamically change this attribute using javascript as per your requirement.

Comment: you can call a javascript function onchange of text box if the text is not same as the default value you can work around on it

Answer (score 0):

add 
    readonly="readonly"..........

please notice : 
readonly - is a markup class

we dont have to write x=x

so we can only write x

hence

```
<input type="text" id="a" value="abc" readonly />
```

also work

Answer (score 0):

Method 1

```
input type="text" id="a" value="abc" disabled="true"
```

Method 2

```
input type="text" id="a" value="abc" readonly="readonly"
```

In first case, text field will be disabled and you will not be allowed to select the value, where as in the second method you can select it, but not able to edit it..

Disabled field are not accessible in successor pages.

You can also dynamically change this attribute using javascript as per your requirement.